# Partner user access to Flow linked from VF

Tags: visualforce, flow

I have a Flow I've created and I want to reference it on a super simple Visualforce page. I created a custom controller to allow me access to the the current User's Account ID.  This page is something that partner community users will access. I have enabled access to the VF page and Apex class on the partner user profile. I tested their access to the Flow by accessing the Flow through a custom button using the Login As feature. That works fine, so I know they can access Flows correctly.  However, when I click the link from the VF page, I get the insufficient privileges error. Is my URL incorrect in the VF page?

Here is the Visualforce page:
[image: Visualforce]

And here is my controller:

[image: controller]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out portal users do not have access when referencing the Flow through a URL.  If you just embed in a Visualforce page and link to that, it works!